# How do I write one method to handle all permutations of an advanced search feature in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

I have an ASP.NET web page that has an advanced search tab. Within this tab I have 10 fields that can be used to refine the search further. I want to write a single method to handle all of the permutations that result from this search.

What is the best way to achieve this? I know that I cannot create a search object to hold all the values and pass that in because the object cannot be exposed from the business layer to the UI layer).

Comment: And is the search performed against a database? If so, what kind?

Comment: the search is performed using a Linq Datasource that is querying MSSQL database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var query = dc.MyTable; // Base query here
if (Field1.Text != "") // Filter Field1
    query = query.Where(x => x.Field1 == Field1.Text);

if (Field2.Text != "") // Filter Field2
    query = query.Where(x => x.Field2 == Field2.Text);

grid.DataSource = query;
```

Comment: I don't know the `And` (extension) method. Did you mean `Where`?

Comment: @GvS The `And` exists in PredicateBuilder... see the link in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a LinqDataSource you can specify in your Where clause something like (not tested):

```
"(@Param1 == String.Empty || Field1 == @Param1) && (@Param2 == String.Empty || Field2 == @Param2) && etc... "
```

Where @Param1, @Param2, etc... are defined as WhereParameters in the control.
I used String.Empty, but you've to use a default based on your parameters' type.

Answer (score 0):

You have these options IMHO:

- [`PredicateBuilder` from Joseph Albahari](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx)
- [dynamic linq](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx) (very flexible, allows to build linq queries from strings)